# Can I re-write the definition of Cauchy sequence

Tags: calculus

Can I re-write the definition of Cauchy sequence as follows:
$$ \forall \varepsilon>0\ \exists N\in\mathbb N:\forall n > N, k \in \mathbb{N} \ |a_n-a_{n+k}|<\varepsilon ?$$

Comment: Seems fine to me